# Which pieces did Mozart write originally for SATB choir a cappella?

Tags: choir, mozart

Specifically:

- it has to be written for *a cappella* performance by a mixed soprano-alto-tenor-bass choir. It can't have a mandatory instrumental part (e.g. piano, organ, string quarter, etc.), but may have an optional instrumental part, e.g. it could be a Choir + Organ piece where the composer has explicitly stated (e.g. in the sheet) that the instrumental may be dropped for some reason (e.g. if the choir is large enough) - these are acceptable.
- it has to be an original Mozart work - KV catalogue index and all. Arrangements of Mozart works by other composers (e.g. a cappella arrangements of Requiem) don't count.
- it may require a solo performer.

Basically, imagine Mozart hearing Viadana's Exultate Justi, saying to himself: "I can do better than that!" and getting straight to work. I'm searching for the result of that!

Comment: In my experience, the topic of finding a Mozart piece suitable for choir performance crops up surprisingly often. I asked the question here _specifically_ because I think that the question will indeed prove useful to future readers (was it bad judgment?). I did my best to word my question in a search-friendly way. Finally, I got both an excellent answer and an excellent answer-finding technique.

Comment: Yeah I agree with Stefan. It's not the first time either I've seen good, sensible questions being held off as off-topic here, see for example http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/15586/retrograde-and-inverted-songs/15600. Personally I think the policy applied in both cases is overly broad. This is not about identifying "a particular song", it is about a well-defined class of compositions. Questions like "how do I learn to play using X technique on instrument Y" invariably have the same, predictable useless answers ("practice, a lot") and are never held off.

Comment: Have you googled "mozart choral satb a capella" yet?  If you haven't, perhaps it would be best to start there.  I did so and find several arrangements available that appear to meet your needs.

Comment: @BobRodes the requirement was: written by Mozart / not an arrangement by another composer. Your google suggestion leads to pages and pages of cold leads. Many results come without provenance so you'd have to still track down to see if it is an original composition or an arrangement by another composer. It might've worked if Mozart had in fact, written tons and tons of a cappella works, and no other composers decided to make a-capella arrangements of his accompanied works. In which case I don't think Stefan would've asked in the first place.

Comment: You can find an extremely comprehensive list of Mozart choral pieces in sheet music at http://www1.cpdl.org/wiki/index.php/Wolfgang_Amadeus_Mozart. Whether he wrote some with instrumental accompaniment or not, you will have to research.

Comment: Yes, I have googled and googled. As @RolandBouman guessed correctly, I found mostly arrangements or non a cappella works. I asked on this site _specifically_ because I though that the question fits snugly with the Q&A format. Guys, Stack Exchange is a Micro FAQ suite of sites, where no well-asked question is undeserving. If your idea of an answer in a FAQ site is "Here's the complete repertoire of Mozart's work, do your research! Alone!", then the music stack exchange might well not make it out of Beta.

Comment: @Roland: you're right, I missed that in your requirements. (Sorry if my post sounded like you hadn't spent enogh time looking for an answer; looking at it again I can see that it might look that way and it wasn't intentional.) I wasn't able to find anything either. Interesting.

Comment: @BobRodes it's ok - no offence taken :) In retrospect, I thought that maybe it is possible to find exactly the desired result with just Google, and my google-foo might just not be good enough. Regardless I still think this "put on hold" policy is way too stringent, or maybe it is used too lightly.

Comment: I will take consolation in knowing that novice choir geeks like me will stumble upon imslp's `List_of_works_by_xxx` tables thanks to this question's answer, making this whole diatribe worth enduring. @RolandBouman +1

Comment: I added this to the meta: http://meta.music.stackexchange.com/questions/731/please-relax-the-policy-on-questions-that-ask-for-examples-of-a-particular-class

Comment: @StefanDragnev, I think it would be helpful if you could go to http://meta.music.stackexchange.com/questions/731/please-relax-the-policy-on-questions-that-ask-for-examples-of-a-particular-class and explain how you thought of your question, and what your expectations were w/re to the answers. Would be great if you could give your feedback. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using this list:

http://imslp.org/wiki/List_of_works_by_Wolfgang_Amadeus_Mozart

I found 2 for mixed chorus. Click the links to download the score.

- [God is Our Refuge, K.20](http://imslp.org/wiki/God_is_Our_Refuge,_K.20_%28Mozart,_Wolfgang_Amadeus%29) ([Youtube video, with score](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fl9VX-DqdCA))
- [Quaerite primum regnum Dei, K.86/73v](http://imslp.org/wiki/Quaerite_primum_regnum_Dei,_K.86/73v_%28Mozart,_Wolfgang_Amadeus%29) ([Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=26C8uQpVeEw))

Both pieces are quite short, just over a minute.

I added a [musescore transcription](http://musescore.com/rpbouman/wa-mozart---god-is-our-refuge-and-strength-kv-20) for God is our Refuge. You can download this score as [musescore file](http://static.musescore.com/173356/465d99987a/score.mscz), [pdf file](http://static.musescore.com/173356/465d99987a/score.pdf), [musicXML file](http://static.musescore.com/173356/465d99987a/score.mxl), [midi](http://static.musescore.com/173356/465d99987a/score.mid), or [mp3](http://static.musescore.com/173356/465d99987a/score.mp3). I also made a [matching videoscore](http://musescore.com/node/173359).

**Update**

Here's another list of Mozart pieces scored for choir (with sheet music provided for each one) at the [Choral Public Domain Library](http://www1.cpdl.org/wiki/index.php/Wolfgang_Amadeus_Mozart). However these might not be originally written for only choir.

http://www1.cpdl.org/wiki/index.php/Wolfgang_Amadeus_Mozart